# Why does my webpage show html code instead of rendering

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I made a code to query brands to show up in the HTML using templates.
but I have been getting the actual HTML to show up instead

```
def index(request):
    form = Search(request.GET or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        content = {
            'form' : form
        }
        brand = Brand.objects.all()
        brand_listing = {
            'brand' : brand
        }
        return render(request, 'homepage/columntemplate.html', content, brand_listing)
```

My HTML tag is {{brand}} placed in the static folder.

```
<div class="flex-container">
<div>{{brand}} </div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
</div>
```

Also is it possible to pass a form and a variable?

Answer (score 1):

this question is old but I just encountered this problem and It was because of the context, you are passing two contexts (content and brand_listing) instead of one.
`context = { 'contents':content, brand_listing:brand_listing}`

so you will use this context list instead

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using specific fields for brand like

```
{{ brand.id }}
{{ brand.name }}
```

here is an example view for your reference

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CroppieImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            #do something
        else:
            return HttpResponse('<h1> Verify Your Data</h1>')
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = CroppieImageForm()
        posts = #something
        profile = #something
        return render(request, 'User/home.html', {
            'posts': posts,
            'profile': profile,
            'form': form
        })
```

Comment: getting the same result just raw HTML which is not rendered, In the rendered html the tags arent there either. also what do those variations mean?

Comment: Can you please share your entire view.py ? If possible also share the html that you are getting  ( inspect it )

Comment: i narrowed it down it seems i am having trouble sending two variables for the template

Comment: This is how i send data to my templates .                                                return render(request, 'User/home.html', {
            'posts': posts,
            'profile': profile,
            'form': form
        })` it would be convenient if you could share your views.py file